# DrRacket procedure body help (boolean-odd? x)

Tags: scheme, racket

An iterative version of odd? for non-negative integer arguments can be written using and, or, and not. To do so, you have to take advantage of the fact that and and or are special forms that evaluate their arguments in order from left to right, exiting as soon as the value is determined. Write (boolean-odd? x) without using if or cond, but using and, or, not (boolean) instead. You may use + and -, but do not use quotient, remainder, /, etc.

Comment: I only see instructions here.  Is there a question?  If you've written code, note that: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."  If you haven't, notice that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What have you done so far?  What didn't work about it?

Comment: (define (boolean-odd? x) your_code_here) 
that's where we should write the code. I've written exactly what is written on my paper.

Write it's body without using if or cond, but using and, or, not (boolean) instead. You may use + and -, but do not use quotient, remainder, /, etc.

Comment: I don't know whatelse I can do. It's just a homework and I don't know how to handle it

Comment: Well, if it's homework, it's presumably for a class of some sort.  What has the class covered so far?

Comment: We have learned recursive and iterative functions. such as factorial, multiplication. Today we've started cons,car,cdr. we did pairs and list of pairs. Putting pairs into the lists with the weirdest ways etc...

Comment: If you've handled multiplication through recursion, then even if you don't have the final answer, you should have some idea of "how to handle it," I think.  This question doesn't require any work with `cons`, `car`, etc.

Comment: yes I wrote my multiplaciton code today. it's '(define fast-mul (lambda (a b) (if (= a 0) 0 (+ b (fast-mul b (- a 1))))))'  but the problem is we didn't learn 'not'. I saw it in the question for the first time and I started to look what it means.

Answer (score 0):

A number is even if two divides it evenly, and odd if there if there is a remainder of one.  In general, when you divide a number *k* by a number *n*, the remainder is one element of the set {0,1,…n-1}.  You can generalize your question by asking whether, when *k* is divided by *n*, the remainder is in some privileged set of remainder values.  Since this is almost certainly homework, I do not want to provide a direct answer to your question, but I'll answer this more general version, without sticking to the constraints of using only `and` and `or`.

```
(define (special-remainder? k n special-remainders)
  (if (< k n)
      (member k special-remainders)
      (special-remainder? (- k n) special-remainders)))
```

This `special-remainder?` recursively divides `k` by `n` until a remainder less than `n` is found.  Then `n` is tested for its specialness.  In the case that you're considering, you'll be able to eliminate `special-remainders`, because you don't need `(member k special-remainders)`. Since you only have one special remainder, you can just check whether `k` *is* that special remainder.

Comment: @DenizAydemir Please be sure that you're accepting this answer _only if_ it's actually useful to you.  I understand why (based on the comments) you may have un-accepted the other answer, but you also have the option of leaving no answer accepted.  Only accept this if this has actually helped you understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A positive odd number can be defined as 1 + 2n. Thus an odd number is:

- If x is 1
- If x is greater than 1 `and` x-2 is odd.

Thus one* solution that is tail recursive/iterative looks like this:

```
(define (odd? x)
  (or (= ...)          ; #t if 1
      (and ...         ; #f if less than 1
           (odd? ...))); recurse with 2 less
```

*having played around with it it's many ways to do do this and still have it iterative and without if/cond.