# Writing a recursive procedure in Scheme. (sum-by-halves a b)

Tags: scheme, racket

One way to sum the integers from a up to b is to divide the interval in half, recursively sum the two halves, and then add the two sums together. If the interval has an odd number of integers, divide as nearly in half as possible. You can use the `floor` function to return the largest integer that is smaller than some real value.

`(define sum-by-halves (lambda (a b) your_code_here))`

Does anyone have an idea to solve this ?

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"*. You've just copied your assignment here, verbatim. This is no fun. Try solving it yourself, it's fun. Show any attempt, post some code by editing your question. Questions that do not follow the guidelines of SO can be closed.

Comment: @WillNess And not only that, this isn't the first question that OP has asked like this;  see [DrRacket procedure body help (boolean-odd? x)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19281849/1281433).  Deniz: Stack Overflow isn't a homework solution factory.  Questions asking for code need demonstrate that you've _tried_ something and are having a  problem with it.  Not having a solution to hand in for a programming assignment doesn't count as a programming problem.  This "question" is mostly a set of instructions.  As to "does anyone have an idea to solve this?"  I expect the answer is "yes."

Comment: do you know about possibility of getting banned from asking question on SO, for posting "bad" questions? Beware, SO can be unforgiving that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to solve a problem recursively, then you need i) to identify the stopping condition and ii) to figure out how to decompose the bigger problem into identical, but smaller, problems.  You've already got 'ii' (except the details).  What will 'i' be?

The stopping condition will be when the two numbers, 'a' and 'b' are identical.  So, your starting point is:

```
(define (sum-by-halves a b)
  (if (= a b)
      a
      ...))
```

For '...' you'll want the 'c' halfway between 'a' and 'b'.

```
(define (sum-by-halves a b)
  (if (= a b)
      a
      (let ((c (div (+ a b) 2)))
        (+ (sum-by-halves a c)
           (sum-by-halves (+ c 1) b)))))
```

By choosing `div` I ensure the `c` will always be an integer and either half or one less than half.  Thus the `(+ c 1)` won't exceed `b`.  Note: code assumes `(<= a b)`.